# Equivalent for SWT's .pack() in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, size, swt, pack

In wxPython, is there a short form of:

```
size = object.GetBestSize()
object.SetSize(size)
```

(For controls or for frames and dialogs.) `.Layout()` only adjusts the sizes of the child controls.

In [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) there's `.pack()` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you set the size of the widget explicitly, they generally already adjust to the right size. If you add widgets to a sizer and tell them to stretch, then that won't be the case, of course. You can also use the sizer's Fit() method to force it too, although I rarely think this is necessary.

Comment: I have a dialog designed in wxFormBuilder. The problem is, that the illustration is wrong, if I don't use an absolute size there. So `self.GetSizer().Fit(self)` is an alternative to the above for frames and dialogs. +++ But if I set a new label to a `Checkbox`, how does it autoresize like a label? Is `GetBestSize` the only choice there?

Comment: If you're going to change the widget during runtime, then you'll probably need to call Layout(). That's what I do when I add/remove widgets. Maybe do a Layout and then a Fit.